# Do i need to know php to make a wordpress theme in bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a website in bootstrap with HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Can I transfer it as a Wordpress theme without knowing PHP?

My website will be a simple website where I will use some Wordpress plugins.

Comment: WP is built in PHP so you need to know _some_. You should start by reading some guides and tutorials about writing WP themes and actually try something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress is built using PHP.

For creating a fresh theme from scratch in wordpress, basic knowledge of php is sufficient. If you are creating a Plugin in Wordpress then PHP is must!

You can learn it quickly from these free tutorials https://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

BootStrap is necessary for building Responsive websites. Of-course you can combine Bootstrap, HTML, CSS and JS in your Wordpress Theme.

The Wordpress API uses it's own function library to define and execute a theme though.

Comment: _"BootStrap is necessary for building Responsive websites"_ - No it's not! It's a grid (+ a bunch of helpers) that can _help_ you building responsive web sites. There are other alternatives, but you actually don't need to use any of them.